# Из чего генерируется и как изменить QSysInfo::machineUniqueId()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17

Собственно, в qt5 есть такая вещь, как `QSysInfo::machineUniqueId()`.
Интересно, как она работает на Windows, MacOS и Linux и какие данные использует?
А также возможный (вероятный) способ обхода

Comment: В Linux это значение из `/etc/machine-id`

Comment: Мне больше интересно про Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно лишь посмотреть [исходники](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp#L2822):

- На Darwin-системах (MacOS и iOS) это значение `kIOPlatformUUIDKey` из их регистра (может кто-то уточнит конкретнее — адекватной документации что это такое я не нашёл)
- На BSD-системах это значение `kern.hostuuid`, запрашиваемое `sysctl`. По факту оно хранится в `/etc/hostid`. см. [`man sysctl`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=3&apropos=0)
- На Linux это `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` (или `/usr/local/var/lib/dbus/machine-id`, как фаллбек). На systemd-системах обычно это симлинк на `/etc/machine-id`. Это случайный uuid, который обычно генерируется во время первой загрузки (или первого запуска dbus). См. документацию [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/MachineId) и [fdo](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html).
- На Win это значение из ключа реестра `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid`. Как обычно, ключи реестра ни кто не документирует, но, судя по всему, это также случайное значение, сгенерированное в момент установки.

Comment: А как достигается глобальная уникальность во время первой загрузки?

Comment: @dIm0n, строгой глобальной универсальности как таковой нет... на всех платформах просто генерируется uuid — случайные 128±бит... ну и просто за счёт того, что число относительно большое вероятность получить два одинаковых достаточно мала.